# How to stack a div absolutely on top of table cells

Tags: html, css

In the second table cell I have a div inside of it that I want to be absolutely positioned right outside of the `<td>`. Currently I have this, but the problem is that the `<td>'s` that sit below this `<td>` are appearing on top of the div. In the end, I am going to have div's inside of each `<td>` and they will appear on rollover. Here is a picture of the issue, the orange `<td>` is when I have my mouse over it. So how can I position the div so that it appears topmost. Not sure if I am using `z-index` properly.

link to picture: [Snapshot of Issue](http://crm-newsletter.com/email-campaign-images/snap2.jpg)

Here's the associated CSS:

```
td.link {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

td div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -100px;
    background: #CCC;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
    <table>
      caption>Emails For MPC Clients</caption>
      <thead>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Link</th>
         <th>Modified</th>
     </thead>
     <tr>
          <td>Live Webinar</td>
          <td class="link">
               <a href="#" target="_blank">liveWebinar.html</a>
              <div>
                  <h2>Some Content goes in here</h2>
              </div>
          </td>
           <td class="date">02/02/2012</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Z-Index Correctly so that is not the issue. Try positioning your table relatively and see if that gets you in the ballpark.

```
table {
position:relative;
    z-index: 100
}

td.link {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}

td div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -100px;
    background: #CCC;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the tables and have everything using standard divs.  then use the z-index accordingly to place the other divs above

It is best to avoid using tables

Comment: I know it isn't standard using tables, but the usage of this table is very appropriate, it is used for tabled data, not layout. I would like to stick with a table for this.

Comment: Why is it best to avoid using tables? Tables serve a certain purpose and do it very well. The school of thought that says "dont use tables" - needs to apply appropriate context when making that comment.